# How to put background image inside textbox

Tags: css, html

does anyone know how to put background image inside a textbox? i want to do is when i click the textbox it will change the background with an image.Does anyone know how to do that?

my current code wont work:

```
<input onfocus="this.style.background='images/activebutton.png'" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS is the **preferred** method

**CSS**

```
<style>
    input[type="text"]:focus{
        background-image: url('images/activebutton.png');
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" />
```

---

If you still want to use JavaScript you need to do like this

```
<input type="text" 
onfocus="this.style.backgroundImage='url(images/activebutton.png)';" 
onblur="this.style.backgroundImage=''"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input class="changeonfocus"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.changeonfocus:focus{
   background-image: url('image.png');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7s5nQ/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="litebox_input">



.litebox_input:focus { 
  background-image: url(images/edit.png);
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  background-position:right;
}
```

Comment: Okay. The first part was the HTML snippet, the input text-box. The second part was the CSS - the class, the textbox was referencing. Also, rather than use "background-repeat: repeat;", use "background-repeat: repeat-y;". To append the image i used to the right,  i used "backgroud-position:right;"

Answer (score 0):

To put a background image inside an `input` element you need to set `background-image` in CSS:

```
input {
    background-image: url('image.png');
}
```

You can do it programmatically via JavaScript by adding/removing a class, or directly using `this.style.backgroundImage`. So here's an example:

```
<input id="i" type="text" />


var i = document.getElementById('i');

i.addEventListener('click', function() {
  i.style.backgroundImage = "url('image.png')";
});
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GCDnu)

Answer (score 0):

Use some css styling:

```
inputBox{
  background:url('images/activebutton.png');

}
```