# how to get mouseover on image ,that image should be textbox background image in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a background image in text box as in image.

I need to display mouse over to that image.

[image]

This image shows the textbox with its background image.

Comment: post your code if you want to be helped

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you read [this amazing page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ? It will help you a lot further if you want some good answers.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958760/how-to-put-background-image-inside-textbox