# Add image inside edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way I could insert image inside a textbox? Not as an icon but like on evernote application where the user is allowed to capture or get a photo to insert it inside the (edittext) notes. Can you give me a sample code, or a useful tutorial? Sorry, I'm kinda slow learner in programming. I've been searching a lot online but I haven't found a suitable tutorial for me.

Comment: Is it this you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958760/how-to-put-background-image-inside-textbox

Comment: I'm searching for an android code, still thank you for giving a link.